# Image with link and overlay hover effect

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, overlay

Please bear with me as i am not very familiar with html/css

I try to output an image with color overlay and link. The text is below because the image will be thumbnail size and it won't fit.

Problem: i can't get the link to be on top of the overlay as i hover so i added the two CSS parts labeled "index" to try to change the index of the link on hover, but now the overlay is gone :(

Maybe i didn't understand how the z-index works or am i wrong with the :hover syntax ?

```
<div class="port_container">
<a href="http://hup.o-zen.de" class="port_link">
<img src="http://google.com" alt="some text" class="port_image">
</a>
<div class="port_overlay">
</div>
</div>
<p>text goes here</p>

.port_container {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 }

.port_image {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }

.port_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #ff6600;
  }

 /* added index*/
 .port_link {
  position: relative;
  transition: z-index 0s;
  z-index: 0;
  }
 /*index on hover*/
.port_link:hover {
 transition: z-index 0.5s ease;
 z-index: 1;
 }

.port_container:hover .port_overlay {
 opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

I read that wrapping the whole div in a link is not fully supported so i wouldn't go that route and hope you can spot my mistake in the code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`.port_overlay` was obscuring the link, adding `pointer-events:none` to it will fix it. I rewrote and improved this to not need to do that, the overlay is part of the image.

Fork this on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/OfficialAntarctica/pen/zNbgod).

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
}
.container a .image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container a .image:before {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ff6600;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
.container a:hover .image:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.container .caption {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <a href="yoursite">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300)"></div> 
   </a>
   <div class="caption">Text goes here.</div> 
</div>
```

*Don't forget to vote if this helped or was way off topic and mark an answer that works as correct with the green tick.*

Comment: Hi. This is great. I removed mix-blend-mode as it is not supported on any IE but i think the rest of the code is compatible to at least IE11.Thank you for your time !

Comment: @B.Anders No problem.